# mongodb server not running as a background process

Tags: database, mongodb, server, process, robo3t

I recently downloaded mongodb and robo 3T. now im new to using mongodb on my system as i normally only use it online. well ever since i installed mongodb, it is meant to run as a background process forever but it never does. for it to even show on my task manager i have to start the service by myself and whenever i restart my laptop its stopped again. my point is, because of this problem, robo 3T hasnt been able to connect to mongodb even though i start the service by myself. did i do anything wrong when installing mongodb and how do i fix this problem?

Comment: See if you have missed any of the steps at: [Run MongoDB Community Edition as a Windows Service](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#run-mongodb-community-edition-as-a-windows-service).

Comment: i checked, deleted and did the installation again, i picked run mongod as a service. still the same thing. ii still have to start the service myself before it starts and even with that, its still not showing up on my robo 3T

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the `.msi` installer to create the MongoD service. Usually I prefer the manual way of doing it. It gives more control and you know what actually happens.

1. Install MongoDB with MSI installer, disable option "Install MongoD as a Service"
2. Create `mongod.cfg` file according to your preferences.

   You may use `<Installation Path>\Server\5.0\bin\mongod.cfg` as template. Pay attention to [Windows Service Options](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#windows-service-options).
3. Install the service by running `mongod.exe --config "<full path of mongod.cfg file>" --install`

Note, you need to run `mongod.exe --install` with Administrator privileges. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod.exe/

Check your Service Manager `services.msc` for any already existing Mongo services. You can remove them with `mongod.exe --config "<mongod.cfg file>" --remove` or `sc.exe delete <service name>`